# How to find $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+xy^2+3y^2}{2x^2+y^2} $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

How to find this limit? $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+xy^2+3y^2}{2x^2+y^2} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+xy^2+3y^2}{2x^2+y^2}$. Then if $t\ne 0$,
$$f(t,t) = \frac13t+\frac43, $$
so $\lim_{t\to 0}f(t,t)=\frac43$. But
$$f(t,2t) = \frac23t + \frac{13}6, $$
so $\lim_{t\to0}f(t,2t)=\frac{13}6$. Therefore $f$ has no limit at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure the limit exists, one easy way to find it is to set $x=0$ and find the limit as $y\to 0$. Or you could set $y=0$ and find the limit as $x\to 0$.

If those two limits are different, your desired limit does not exist. This is also true if one of those two limits does not exist.

Those facts are enough to solve your particular problem. In general, however, even finding both those limits and seeing that they are equal does not prove that your desired limit exists. You need to consider that possibility in other, similar problems.